# I'm making a 24-hour clock

Tags: java, arrays, clock

I'm making a 24-clock. I have the code below. My problem is that the `int[]` time is equal to `[0, 0, 0]` and prints it out every iteration. 
Some more information that might help you. I have the `Array TimeCounter` as `[hours, minutes, seconds]`. The reset methods set selected int values to zero, stay the same, or increase by one. The nested while loops are for going through the clock.

```
public static int hours;
public static int minutes;
public static int seconds;
public static int [] TimeCounter = {hours, minutes, seconds};

//End of day
public static void reset(int [] midNight){
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}

//End of a minute
public static void resetSeconds(int [] endOfMin){
    minutes++;
    seconds = 0;
}

//End of a Hour
public static void resetMinutes(int [] endOfHour){
    hours++;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}
public static void run(int [] time){
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(time));
    while (hours < 25){
        if (hours == 24){
            if (minutes == 59){
                if (seconds == 60){
                    reset(time);
                }
            }
        }
        while (minutes < 61){
            if (minutes == 59){
                if (seconds == 60){
                    resetMinutes(time);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(time));
                }
            }
            while (seconds < 61){
                if (seconds == 60){
                    resetSeconds(time);
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(time));
                seconds++;

            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(time));
            minutes++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(time));
        hours++;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    run(TimeCounter);
}
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to use object-oriented concepts at all for this program? Do the instructions force you to use static for everything? Ugh.

Comment: You really should get rid of the array and just use the variables.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - It seems that intro programming classes these days start with writing procedural code in OO language.  Many examples given have `main` method only.

Comment: @PM77-1: yep, you're probably right, but going through this type of code is like nails on a chalk board for me.

Answer (score 5):

The ints held by the array are not the same as those in the variables. Yes, you initialize the array with the variables, but after that, the array int items are on their own. If you want to increment an int item in the array, you must do so directly: `myArray[someIndex]++`.

As an aside, and as per my comment, are you not allowed to use object-oriented concepts at all for this program? Do the instructions force you to use static for everything? The reason I ask this is because a much better program would not use an array as you're doing but would have int fields for seconds, minutes, and hours, and would encapsulate the logic for rolling over seconds to minutes to hours. This would be *much* easier to maintain and enhance.

---

**Edit**
For example:

```
public class FooClock {
   public static final int SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
   public static final int MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;
   private static final int NOON = 12;
   private int hours;
   private int minutes;
   private int seconds;
   private boolean am = true;
   private String formatString = "%02d:%02d:%02d %s";

   public FooClock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, boolean am) {
      this.hours = hours;
      this.minutes = minutes;
      this.seconds = seconds;
      this.am = am;
   }

   public void incrementSeconds() {
      seconds++;
      normalize();
   }

   public void incrementMinutes() {
      minutes++;
      normalize();
   }

   public void incrementHours() {
      hours++;
   }

   public void normalize() {
      if (seconds >= SECONDS_PER_MINUTE) {
         minutes += seconds / SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
         seconds %= SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
      }
      if (minutes >= MINUTES_PER_HOUR) {
         hours += minutes / MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
         minutes %= MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
      }
      if (hours >= 2 * NOON) {
         hours %= (2 * NOON);
         am = true;
      }
      if (hours >= NOON) {
         am = false;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      String amString = am ? "AM" : "PM";
      return String.format(formatString, hours, minutes, seconds, amString);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int total_seconds = 24 * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE * MINUTES_PER_HOUR;

      FooClock fooClock = new FooClock(0, 0, 0, true);
      System.out.println(fooClock);
      for (int i = 0; i < total_seconds; i++) {
         fooClock.incrementSeconds();
         System.out.println(fooClock + " ");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question, but I got it this morning by doing a for-loop. I posted it below if you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was change the while-loop into a for-loop using the almost exactly the same code. I also added somethings like "am" and "pm"

```
public static int hours;

public static int minutes;

public static int seconds;

public static int [] TimeCounter = {hours, minutes, seconds};

public static void run(int h, int m, int s){
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
    seconds = s;
    TimeCounter[0] = hours;
    TimeCounter[1] = minutes;
    TimeCounter[2] = seconds;
    String timeOfDay = "am";

    for (hours = 0; hours < 25; hours++){
        TimeCounter[0] = hours;
        if (hours == 12){
            timeOfDay = "pm";
        }
        System.out.println(TimeCounter[0] + " : " + TimeCounter[1] + " : " + TimeCounter[2] + " " + timeOfDay);
        if (hours == 24){
            reset(TimeCounter);
            break;
        }else{
            for (int minutes = 0; minutes < 61; minutes++){
                TimeCounter[1] = minutes;
                System.out.println(TimeCounter[0] + " : " + TimeCounter[1] + " : " + TimeCounter[2] + " " + timeOfDay);
                }
                if (minutes == 60){
                    minutes = 0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    for (seconds = 0; seconds < 61; seconds++){
                        TimeCounter[2] = seconds;
                        System.out.println(TimeCounter[0] + " : " + TimeCounter[1] + " : " + TimeCounter[2] + " " + timeOfDay);
                        if (seconds == 60){
                            seconds = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}

//End of day
public static void reset(int [] midNight){
    TimeCounter[0] = 0;
    TimeCounter[1] = 0;
    TimeCounter[2] = 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    run(0, 0, 1);
}
```

}

Comment: if anyone wants the code for the 12-hour version of this, just comment to this post and I'll post it

Comment: I'm not sure what your output is supposed to show, but yours looks like it might be off. Are you sure that this code is correct? What are the specific assignment requirements, and what is the output supposed to look like?  An example of the type of program I meant has been posted as an addendum to my answer.

Comment: yeah, I got little help with it and it started working. I think this is a different version because one of the versions had a malfunctioning second counter